# Not available public variable

Tags: c++, class

```
class A()
{};

class B : public A()
{public:int x};
int main()
{
 A* test = new B();
 test->x = 1;
 return 0;
}
```

Why x is not available? And how can i fix it?Thx.

Comment: perhaps try changing `A* test = new B();` to `B* test = new A();`

Comment: Why should it be available?

Comment: Same applies for any (member) variable references, as described in the dupe.

Comment: @FeatheredOrcian `B* test = new A()` is not valid code

Comment: @UmNyobe ok just threw that out there honestly didn't even think about what I wa writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the compiler is only checking for x in the methods/members of class A. You've declared it as A, and it really either needs to be B, or it needs to be cast to B when you use it.

Also, is this homework? It seems contrived.